# Manga where everyone lives in an underground city because the surface world is no longer liveable due to some catastrophic events

Tags: story-identification, manga

The manga is shōnen, with black and white art. The main character is male and has a scavenger/thief-like job. The main character's appearance is of a teenage or young adult, wearing a scarf and hood, like tribe people in a desert.

- Sometimes they need to go to the surface to collect materials and lost technology.
- The civilization thrives in underground cities.
- There are also monsters and such.

I'm confident enough that in the first few panels I read, a young adult stares down into the abyss crater in which underground city is built while crouching, from a top down angle view. This is also the cover, with the young adult male stand in such a pose with dominant brown yellowish color like desert theme. Written text vertically in Japanese.

The Main Character definitely has a scarf and a dagger on the belt and has lone wolf personality. He explores underground alone in early chapter.

Comment: Are there any other details you can recall about this manga? Do you remember anything about how the surface world was ruined? Or how people survive underground without sunlight? Do you remember about when you read this, and how many chapters were available at the time?

Comment: Maybe Tengen Toppa Gurren Lagann which is mainly known as anime, but has a manga?

Comment: Ayanashi? Underground society; surface ruined by monsters, lone wolf male protagonist. Dagger-like weapon on hand, not belt. No scarf. Vol 1 cover is mostly yellow and black, but text is horizontal. First chapter isn't him exploring alone. So some matches, plenty of differences.

Answer (score 4):

This is not *[Last Order](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/last-order)*. But it has some similarities.

> Takes place in the world after the "end" and follows machine soldier Lear, who has been following the "Last Order" and continuing an endless war for over 100 years.

There's two protagonists; the first is Lear, a female combat robot that is the sole survivor of the monster apocalypse; her last orders were to defend the island, which she continues to do well after losing contact with any humans.

[image: Monsters]

The part you recall is from the other protagonist. As you mention, he lives in an underground society, where many live as scavengers. Only some are able to actually go to the surface - he is not one of them.

I wouldn't call their civilization "thriving", but they're not doomed or anything, and it's implied they've been living in a tribal state at least since the apocalypse. The technological advances of the past are basically myth now, with general demonizations of machines.

[image: Religion against the machines]

Comment: Skimming through the early chapters; I don't see the male MC wearing a scarf. It's possible he puts one on later, but it's not a defining characteristic or anything.

Comment: I'm sorry i dont think last order is right manga. I read it as soon u answer this. But i dont found any similarities for first chapter with my references. Because i confident enough that in the first few panel i read, a young adult stare down into the abyss crater which underground city is build in crouch position with top down angle view. I can't found this. But if u can find similarities please tell me. Thank you

Comment: @Ryuzaki The first two chapters focus entirely on the female robot; the underground civilization starts in the 3rd chapter, and the very first chapter is pre-apocalypse. You might need to skip ahead to that, if you haven't already. It's been a while since I've read this so I don't recall if there's a specific scene with a crater or not. If this definitely isn't it, I can try searching for something else. Alternatively, you could check out the recommendations tab on the anime-planet link I included; it might be similar enough that it shows up there, and maybe you can recognize the cover.

Comment: I checked already i dont recon the chapter 3 nor the cover in ur recommend link. But I remember the cover , young adult male stand in such a pose with dominant brown yellowish color like dessert theme. Written text vertically in Japanese. Also Definitely MC use scarf have stash dagger on the belt and has lone wolf personality. Explore underground alone in early chapter not like Last Order manga u mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this post because I was looking for it too. I think I finally found it though, it is called *[Ayanashi](https://myanimelist.net/manga/104186/Ayanashi)*.

> In this world, humanity has been driven underground to live like
> moles, hiding from the fearsome monsters which roam the surface. The
> monsters are impervious to every sort of weapon known to man. The only
> ones with the power to defeat them...are the Ayanashi.
>
> One day, in one such underground city, a pair of siblings encounter a
> mysterious boy covered in wounds. The boy introduces himself as Holo,
> and in the following days slowly opens up to the pair...until a
> monster from the surface descends upon the city, laying waste to
> everything in its path. Holo stands to face the threat, brandishing a
> flaming short sword attached to his right arm. And so, the story of
> bringing light back to a world of everlasting darkness begins.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This seems close, but the cover isn't an exact match; can you provide any pages to show the panel described in the question?